# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource

Tags: spring

My Stack Trace is as shown below:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>     org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:154)
>     org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.registerComponents(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:149)
>     org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:88)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>     org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>     org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: I added spring-aop.jar in my classpath.

Comment: it's a classloading issue. Be sure you really have the spring-aop.jar file in the classpath and that it is present just one time

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Thanks for your reply. I checked my classpath and there is only one spring-aop.jar. Whatelse could be the reason behind getting that exception???

Answer (score 1):

check the classpath once  again,you may forget to add spring aop.jar.

i did the same mistake and after watching the result i added that jar and application working fine.